# No view state in Spring WebFlow

Tags: spring-webflow-2

I am using springwebflow 2.0 in my application.    
Since the application is growing, I am having large number of webflows. Now I need to create a separate webflow for a particular event like "onchange event of dropdowns." 
For all the jsps in my application on the event of "onchange" I want a separate webFlow DomainFetcher-flow.xml to run and return some value.

```
So far my domainFetcher-flow.xml looks like 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow    http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd">
 <on-start>
     <evaluate expression="domainFetcher.fetchTableDomain()"    result="conversationScope.selectDataJSON"/>
 </on-start>
```

Right now I am getting an exception that at least one view state should be defined. 
So looking for a solution...

Comment: 1) Post full exception stack trace. 2)Is this the full flow definition file?

Comment: ya Prasad this is full flow definition file. The question is that can we declare a flow with out any view states?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can define a subflow without a view state. For example, you have below parent flow which invokes subflow subflow-flow.xml as :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd">  
        ... 
        <subflow-state id="subflow-flow" subflow="subflow-flow">
            <transition on="endOfSubflow" to="someStateWithMessage"/>
        </subflow-state>
        ...
    </flow>
```

Then in subflow you can perform some action. You can define subflow-flow.xml as:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd"
            start-state="start">            
        <action-state id="start">
            <evaluate expression="yourAction.performSomeAction(flowRequestContext)"/>
            <transition to="endOfSubflow"/>
        </action-state>
        ...
        <end-state id="endOfSubflow"/>
    </flow>
```

In your action class:

```
    public class YourAction{
    ...
    public void performSomeAction(RequestContext context){
        //do what you want in this method.

    }
    ...
    }
```

Hope this helps.